# Selenium switching to new URL / Can't find elements on new URLredirect

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am new in automatization and i need to make step by step finding guy in list, then go to his profile and check some information about him. When i am working at my first URL sending keys to Search field, finding guy that i need one and click working perfect. But when i am opening guy profile i can't adress to any element on this page using selenium, getting this exception, that meaning that he can't find such elements. But when i am using Chrome Console and jQuery it works perfectly finding my element and making actions with this.

```
> (An unhandled exception of type
> 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
> Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"id","selector":"contentIFrame1"})
```

I still thing that webdriver is working with my first page, and suggestions pls.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace RLC_AccCheck_1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("c:\\Work\\Selenium"))
      {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("URL")
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        //Catherine Burke
        //Console.Write("name=");
        string name = "Catherine Burke";//Console.ReadLine();

        IWebElement frame = driver.FindElement(By.Id("contentIFrame0"));

        IWebDriver driverFrame = driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);

        IWebElement search = driverFrame.FindElement(By.Id("crmGrid_findCriteria"));

        search.SendKeys(name);

        IWebElement searchImg = driverFrame.FindElement(By.Id("crmGrid_findCriteriaImg"));
        searchImg.Click();

        IWebElement row;
        try
        {
          row = driverFrame.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ms-crm-List-Data .ms-crm-List-Row:nth-child(1)"));
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(name + " is not found");
          Console.ReadKey();
          return;
        }

        IWebElement record = row.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ms-crm-List-DataCell:nth-child(3) a"));
        if (record.Text == name)
        {
          record.Click();
          //record.GetAttribute("href")
          Console.WriteLine(name + " is found");
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine(name + " is not found");
        }

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        String currentURL = driver.Url;
        Console.WriteLine(currentURL + " is current URL ");

        var windowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;

        //This frame and all id/class writing below tags is not located

        IWebElement frame1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("contentIFrame1"));
        IWebDriver driverFrame1 = driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame1);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        IWebElement image = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Fax_label"));
        image.Click();

        //driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);

        IWebElement test = driver.FindElement(By.Id("FormSecNavigationControl-Icon"));
        test.Click();

        IWebElement recordType = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#ddsm_recordtype .multiSel")); 
        Console.WriteLine(record.Text);

        Console.ReadKey();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: New URL is still in the same window

Answer (score 0):

Does your user profile page make use of jQuery windows?

It could be that your webDriver is focusing on a different window than the one containing your elements.

If this is the problem, see the previous post [How do I interact with a popup window with Mink, Selenium 2, and Behat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721766/how-do-i-interact-with-a-popup-window-with-mink-selenium-2-and-behat/34273053#34273053)

Comment: New URL is still in the same window

Comment: The only other thought that comes to mind is that your selenium scripts tried to find elements on the page before the page has finished loading.  A nasty fix is to tell your script to sleep(xx) after redirect, but you could essentially write a function which waits for a response.  Hope you find your solution.